# Rectangles drawn on Tkinter Canvas are not drawn tightly with others

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, canvas

I tried to draw rectangles which will occupy the entire canvas
But, when I tried to do this, I noticed that between the rectangles there is an indent.

Like this:

[image]

I was expecting that rects will be drawn without these indents.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

blocks = 10
block_size = 40
res = (block_size*blocks,)*2

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Main Window')
        self.geometry(f'{res[0]}x{res[1]}')
        self.c = tk.Canvas(self, width=res[0], height=res[1], highlightthickness=0, bg='black')
        self.c.pack()
        for row in range(blocks):
            for col in range(blocks):
                x = col*block_size
                y = row*block_size
                self.c.create_rectangle(x,y,x+block_size,y+block_size,fill='white')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainWindow()
    main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `outline` of each rectangle. Hide it with `outline=''`.

If you do that, though, you won't see your rectangles (since they're all white), so maybe color them like a chess board with

```
color = 'black' if (row + col) % 2 else 'white'
self.c.create_rectangle(x, y, x + block_size, y + block_size, fill=color, outline='')
```

to begin with:

[image]